# Can't connect to oracle sqlplus on RDS amazon from microsoft Server R2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using following-

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//endpoint:1521:ORCL", "dbname", "password"
);
```

I'm getting following error-

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at MyServer.<init>(MyServer.java:21)
    at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:42)
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: class not exception: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Could you copy/paste the stack trace?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @BorisPavlović suggested, please add the complete error message (including the stack trace, etc.) to your post . If you provide more (relevant) information about your problem you are more likely to get a qualified answer. Please also take a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at MyServer.<init>(MyServer.java:21)
        at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:42)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the oracle jdbc driver to the classpath